# atol(), atof(), atoi() function behaviours, is there a stable way to convert from/to string/integer?

Tags: c++, c, function

In these days I'm playing with the C functions of **atol(), atof() and atoi()**, from a blog post I find a tutorial and applied:

Here are my results:

```
void main()
{
    char a[10],b[10];
    puts("Enter the value of a");
    gets(a);
    puts("Enter the value of b");
    gets(b);
    printf("%s+%s=%ld and %s-%s=%ld",a,b,(atol(a)+atol(b)),a,b,(atol(a)-atol(b)));
    getch();
}
```

There is `atof()` which returns the float value of the string and `atoi()` which returns integer value.

Now to see the difference between the 3 I checked this code:

```
main()
{
    char a[]={"2545.965"};
    printf("atol=%ld\t atof=%f\t atoi=%d\t\n",atol(a),atof(a),atoi(a));
}
```

The output will be

```
atol=2545 atof=2545.965000 atoi=2545

char a[]={“heyyou”};
```

Now when you run the program the following will be the output (**why?**, is there any solution to convert pure strings to integer?)

```
atol=0 atof=0 atoi=0
```

The string should contain the numeric value. Now modify this program as

```
char a[]={“007hey”};
```

The output in this case (tested in Red Hat Linux) will be

```
atol=7 atof=7.000000 atoi=7
```

so the functions have taken 007 only, not the remaining part (**why?**).

Now consider this

```
char a[]={“hey007?};
```

The output of the program will be

```
atol=0 atof=0.000000 atoi=0
```

So I just want to convert my strings to numbers and then again to the same text. I played with these functions, and, as you see, I'm getting really interesting results.

Why is that?

Are there any other functions to convert from/to string/integer and vice versa?

**EDIT:**

So as an input, if I take some names, or whatever, I will convert them to integers/floats... then apply some other functions.

Also I'm curious about if I will take the same output with the same inputs when I use any of your suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The high-end solution to this problem, given that you also added a C++ tag, is to use [Boost lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

Comment: +1 for the C++ answer (given the tag). Reading the code, however, I think a pure C solution may be required.

Answer (score 4):

There is no inconsistency per se:

- `atoi` parses to `int`
- `atof` parses to `float`
- `atol` parses to `long`
- All three parses the prefix of a string until it hits the end, or an invalid character

  - The rest of the string (if any) is ignored

---

> So i just want to convert my strings to number and then again to same text

So the number doesn't have to be an intelligble interpretation of the string? And how long can the string be, and how big can the numbers be?

A string can be decoded as a `byte[]`. Is this good enough?

Perhaps you need something like [public key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)?

Comment: okey i see that however my results are "zero", how can i build a stable program using these functions?

Comment: @Berkay: do you want an encoding/decoding algorithm, or do you want to parse `"10"` to the `int` value `10`? What would you parse `"xxx"` into, then?

Comment: @polygenelubricants, my goal is to convert string(only consists characters to integer)

Comment: @Berkay: does the integer have to be fit in 32-bit/64-bit? Because this will not be possible for longer strings.

Comment: so as an input if i take some names not more than 32 bits. My aim is to convert everything to integers/floats that i take as an input from the users.

Comment: @Berkay: I'm not familiar with C/C++ spec, but each `char` of a string is essentially a number (e.g `'0' == 48` in ASCII encoding), so you can work like this if this is what you want, treating a string as a base-256 number. Such mapping will not work for long strings, though. `"hey you"` is not a 32-bit string. You can use an arbitrary precision integer library to represent longer string as larger numbers, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strtol()` and `strtod()`, which are far superior than `atol()` and `atof()` because they allow you to test whether the conversion succeeded.  The `ato_()` functions fail silently, as you saw when you tried to convert `"heyyou"`.

Comment: ok will check it. do they work for strings just containing characters?

Comment: @Berkay:  These functions convert numbers, in their string representations, to some numeric type.  What behavior do you expect if you give them a string that doesn't start with a number?

Comment: i just want to play with numbers. so as an input if i take some names or whatever i will convert them to integers/floats... then apply some other functions. Also i'm curious about if i take same output with different inputs with strtol and strtod? thanks for your help.

Comment: @Berkay:  But what do you expect the result to be?  Do you want integers containing the bit-representations of the characters?  Do you want some kind of base conversion applied to the characters in the text (e.g., base64 encoding)?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you want to create a bijective mapping between arbitrary character strings and real numbers.

That's not what the `atol()`, `atoi()` and `atof()` functions are for - they're for converting the subset of strings that represent numbers in base 10 into the corresponding `long`, `int` or `float` value (if possible).

There is no built-in function for creating the bijective mapping that you're after - particularly since you haven't actually specified how you'd want the mapping to work.  Of course, it *is* possible to write such a mapping function in C.  The simplest way is just to treat the string as a sequence of digits in a base-255 number (the 256th character value, `'\0'` cannot form part of a C string), with the N least-significant digits representing the string's length (where N is chosen according to your requirements).  Note that if you want to do this with strings of arbitrary length, you'll need to work with a "Big Integer" library (like GMP, or OpenSSL's BigNum) - the longest type in standard C, "long long" cannot be mapped one-to-one onto the set of C strings that include strings longer than 8 characters, because its guaranteed range includes only 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 unique values.

Comment: thanks for the answer, your first sentence is describing what i'm looking for... great advice.thanks